# ISO 7816-4 APDU command Select File and Write Record

Tags: android, nfc, apdu, hce, contactless-smartcard

I am trying to communicate between PN532 and HCE on Android with ISO 7816-4 command, I am successfully select the AID (a DF), but when I select the EF under that DF (that EF does not exist, so I assume that Select command will create that EF), and then write the records to that EF but it display like this:

```
inList passive target
write:  4A 1 0
read:   4B 1 1 0 4 60 4 8 23 5A 4D 5 75 80 70 2
write:  40 1 0 A4 4 0 7 F0 1 2 3 4 5 6 0
read:   41 0 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 44 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 21

Successfully hehe 

48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 44 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 21    Hello Desktop!
write:  40 1 0 A4 2 C 1 1 0
read:   41 0 48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 44 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 21
Not enough space
write:  40 1 0 D2 0 0 7 42 41 4F 47 49 41 40 0
read:   41 0 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 61 6E 64 72 6F 69 64 3A 20 30
Not enough space
write:  40 1 0 D2 0 2 4 44 4F 41 4E 0
read:   41 0 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 61 6E 64 72 6F 69 64 3A 20 31
Not enough space
write:  40 1 0 B2 0 0 7 42 41 4F 47 49
read:   41 0 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 61 6E 64 72 6F 69 64 3A 20 32
Not enough space
write:  40 1 0 B2 0 2 4 44 4F 41 4E 0
read:   41 0 4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 61 6E 64 72 6F 69 64 3A 20 33
Not enough space
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here?

On Android, the log is :

```
04-15 09:36:54.024: D/HostEmulationManager(929): notifyHostEmulationData
04-15 09:36:54.024: W/System.err(17710): [B@41ed5970
04-15 09:36:54.024: I/HCEDEMO(17710): Received: ???????BAOGI
04-15 09:36:54.024: D/HostEmulationManager(929): Sending data
04-15 09:36:54.164: D/BrcmNfcJni(929): RoutingManager::stackCallback: event=0x17
04-15 09:36:54.164: D/BrcmNfcJni(929): RoutingManager::stackCallback: NFA_CE_DATA_EVT;       h=0x302; data len=10
04-15 09:36:54.164: D/HostEmulationManager(929): notifyHostEmulationData
04-15 09:36:54.164: W/System.err(17710): [B@41ed5e20
04-15 09:36:54.164: I/HCEDEMO(17710): Received: ?????DOAN??
04-15 09:36:54.174: D/HostEmulationManager(929): Sending data
04-15 09:36:54.885: D/BrcmNfcJni(929): RoutingManager::stackCallback: event=0x19
04-15 09:36:54.885: D/HostEmulationManager(929): notifyHostEmulationDeactivated
04-15 09:36:54.885: I/HCEDEMO(17710): Deactivated: 0
04-15 09:36:54.885: D/HostEmulationManager(929): Unbinding from service  ComponentInfo{de.grundid.hcedemo/de.grundid.hcedemo.MyHostApduService}
04-15 09:36:54.895: E/BrcmNfcNfa(929): UICC[0x0] is not activated
```

It displays that it can receive some data, but it misses some elements I want to transmit, but, from PN532, when I use read records, it does not display these data?

Comment: You shall NOT assume that if an EF does not exist, Select command will create that EF. You need to create the EF using CREATE FILE command.

Comment: Sorry, but I could not find CREATE FILE command, only SELECT FILE command?

Comment: The link for the commands I use is here:
http://www.cardwerk.com/smartcards/smartcard_standard_ISO7816-4_6_basic_interindustry_commands.aspx

Comment: You should refer to ISO 7816-9 for CREATE FILE command

Comment: @David The file system part is completely irrelevant as -- looking at the R-APDUs -- there obviously is no file system implementation behind the Android HCE service that Bao Doan is communicating with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The commands that your Android HCE emulated smartcard application understands and processes are completely up to you (as long as they are formatted as valid ISO 7816-4 APDUs).

In your case, your Android HCE service obviously processes the SELECT (by DF name) APDU,

```
00 A4 04 00 07 F0010203040506 00
```

and gives this as a response:

```
48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 44 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 21 ("Hello Desktop!" when interpreted as ASCII)
```

(Note that this response is not a valid response APDU according to ISO 7816-4 as it lacks a status word.)

The next command you send is an invalid SELECT (by EF) command:

```
00 A4 02 0C 01 01 00
```

For that command, Lc should be 2 and the EF identifier should consist of two bytes if following ISO 7816-4. In response to that, your Android HCE service again sends

```
48 65 6C 6C 6F 20 44 65 73 6B 74 6F 70 21 ("Hello Desktop!" when interpreted as ASCII)
```

(Note that this response is not a valid response APDU according to ISO 7816-4 as it lacks a status word.)

So I would guess, that your Android HCE service performs a check like this:

```
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] apdu, Bundle extras) {
    if (apdu[1] == (byte)0xA4) {
        return "Hello Desktop!".getBytes("US-ASCII");
    }
}
```

The next command that you send is a malformed WRITE RECORD command that tries to write "BAOGIA@" in the first record of the cuirrently selected file (malformed, because a WRITE RECORD command normally does not have an Le field):

```
00 D2 00 00 07 42 41 4F 47 49 41 40 00
```

As a response your Android HCE service sends:

```
4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 61 6E 64 72 6F 69 64 3A 20 30 ("Message from android: 0" when interpreted as ASCII)
```

(Note that this response is again not a valid response APDU according to ISO 7816-4 as it lacks a status word.)

You then repeat the WRITE RECORD command with a different record payload and after that you send two malformed READ RECORD commands:

```
00 D2 00 02 04 44 4F 41 4E 00
00 B2 00 00 07 42 41 4F 47 49
00 B2 00 02 04 44 4F 41 4E 00
```

As a response your Android HCE service sends:

```
4D 65 73 73 61 67 65 20 66 72 6F 6D 20 61 6E 64 72 6F 69 64 3A 20 xx ("Message from android: X" when interpreted as ASCII)
```

Where xx seems to be an ASCII digit X that is incremented for each received command.

So I would guess, that your Android HCE service looks like this:

```
private int mCommandCounter = 0;
public byte[] processCommandApdu(byte[] apdu, Bundle extras) {
    String response;
    if (apdu[1] == (byte)0xA4) {
        response = "Hello Desktop!";
    } else {
        response = "Message from android: " + Integer.toString(mCommandCounter);
        ++mCommandCounter;
    }
    return response.getBytes("US-ASCII");
}
```

So, to summarize this, your Android HCE service will understand and process **only** those commands that **you** (or whoever develops it) implement. So it is up to you what commands you can send to the HCE device. There is **no** file system behind it. ISO 7816-4 only *suggests* a file system layout for smartcard applications.

Comment: You are right Michael, but how can I use the existence structure of I so 7816-4 instead of building my own commands?

Comment: The Android HCE emulated smartcard application does **not have any** existing file structure. If **you** want **your** HCE application to accept certain commands, **you** have to implement them on the Android side. These commands can, **of course**, be commands that mimic a file system structure.